# Calculate combined return on corp. bond traded multiple times?

Tags: bond, return

I hope this is an okay place to ask this:

Case: Assume you find a corporate bond you want to invest in. You then invest in it below par several times over the years, and you also sell bits of your holdings above par. It then matures, and you get your remaining nominal amount back at par. You therefore have uneven cash flows. Let’s assume the interest is fixed rate, although FRN can also come into play.

**Question: What is the most correct and the most market-conform way to calculate annualised returns on the corporate bond investment, according to fixed income/debt asset management, if you calculate the return for the multiple investments and divestments in this bond, as a whole? Pooling all the cash flows, the buys, sells and coupons and the redemption.**

Thoughts on solution:
I could divide it up per buy, as an individual investment, but that quickly becomes messy, particularly, how to get to ONE single return on the bond.

I could use IRR, but that would factor in the time value of money, and I am not sure that is the norm in debt asset management? The most common seems to be holding period returns, which then are annualised – but this method does not apply when I have multiple buys and sells in each paper.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter whether you buy/sell above or below face value?

Comment: It likely does not matter. I just wanted to add more colour, and also make it clear that the investments were done at different prices, and exited at different prices, in case that fact would rule out some otherwise simpler approach.

Comment: Also how does it differ from investing in a stock- sometimes selling some, sometimes buying some more, sometimes receiving dividends?

Comment: It is likely the same mechanics. I ask what the most market-conform way of calculating this in relation to debt. In debt, there are many debt-specific ways to calculate returns, but I had yet to find one that covered the above. From the responses so far, it seems there might not be any.

Answer (score 1):

IRR *is* actually the best way to measure the performance of this strategy. In fixed income investing it's more commonly called *yield*, but the principle is the same - the effective rate of return you get on your investment.

IRR is simply a measurement of what interest rate you could invest (or borrow) at to get the same cash flows over the life of the portfolio.

Comment: Would IRR not assume that all cash flows are reinvested? In this case, it is more likely to be invested into another investment (another bond).

Comment: In a way, yes - it assumes that _all_ cash flows could be invested (or borrowed) at that rate (not necessarily the same bond). It doesn't mean that they _have_ to be reinvested, but it's a way to understand what the IRR _means_.

Comment: Note that there exists a modified IRR (called appropriately enough MIRR) where you can specify a different rate for reinvestment of cash flows from the main investment.

Comment: The IRR method does not assume cash flows are reinvested. That's an unfortunate misconception also advanced by some academics.

Comment: Re-examining an Old Question: Does the IRR Method Implicitly Assume a Reinvestment Rate? https://www.jstor.org/stable/24331033

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic choices for calculating investment returns: time-weighted or money-weighted. You can find a straightforward explanation with examples [here](https://www.investorsedge.cibc.com/en/learn/time-weighted-vs-money-weighted-rates-of-return.html).

The important difference between the two methods is that time-weighted returns do not account for the effect of cash flows. For this reason, institutional (bond) funds typically report time-weighted returns because managers do not control cash flows to/from the fund. Retail managers may report money-weighted returns (e.g. IRR and friends) to individual clients so the latter can view the performance effects of their own allocation decisions.

To find the time-weighted return on your investment (aka position), calculate a total return $TR_t = {Price_{end} + Coupons + Accrued \over Price_{start}} - 1$ for each date on which the size of your position changed, then geometrically link those returns as shown in the example I cited above $PR = \prod \limits_{t=0}^T (1 + TR_t) - 1$. To annualize, you need the calendar basis of the bond e.g. 30/360; using Excel terminology it would be $PR^{360 \over DAYS360(start,end)}$, where `start` and `end` are the first and last dates you held that position. If you held to maturity then that would be the end date.

Comment: I do not think time-weighted return is appropriate here because OP _wants_ to account for multiple investments and divestments. TWR with a single instrument will just give you the annualized performance of that instrument, not of the _strategy_ of when to invest/divest. _Fund_ managers use TWR to measure the performance of their _fund_, ignoring investors coming and going.